# C#: Create strong reference between objects, without one referencing the other

Tags: c#

Suppose I have 2 classes, Foo and Bar.
Foo does not have (and cannot have) a relation to Bar.

However, I want a bar instance to stay alive, as long as it's foo instance stays alive.
Is there any way of doing so, without foo actually referencing bar?

Thanks,
Koen

Comment: When you are trying to change the way the garbage collector works, you should probably take a good look at your design and see if it can be changed to work within the language. That said: Interesting question! =)

Comment: Why make life hard for yourself by rejecting the trivial solution?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sounds like they have some sort of dependency issues which preclude them from doing so.

Comment: Why do you have to do this without having a reference to bar?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have a look at the [ConditionalWeakTable Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287757.aspx).

> Enables compilers to dynamically attach object fields to managed objects.

It's essentially a dictionary where both the key and the value are a WeakReference, and the value is kept alive as long as the key is alive.

For example, you can define a

```
ConditionalWeakTable<Foo, Bar> table
```

and add a Foo/Bar pair. The Bar instance is kept alive as long as a reference to the Foo instance exists. You can find the Bar instance for the Foo instance by looking at the table.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to give suggestions without knowing exactly what you're trying to achieve, or what you mean by "alive".  Normally you shouldn't need to worry about lifetime of managed objects: they "die" naturally when they're no longer referenced.

But to do what you appear to want, either your `Foo` instance must reference the `Bar` instance, or some other object must reference both in order to create the link.  It could be a reference to a `Bar` instance as a `System.Object`, i.e. `Foo` doesn't need to know about the `Bar` Type.

Answer (score 0):

Bar can only not be finalized if SOMETHING has a reference to it.  Just have Foo tell that thing when it can let go of Bar.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a public **object** field called BarReference in type Foo?
Someone outside of Foo should set the proper instance of Bar to this property.
As long as there is a reference to the  bar instance it won't be GCed AND using object Foo doesn't know anything about Bar type.

Comment: "Foo does not have (and cannot have) a relation to Bar"

Comment: **Type** Foo doesn't have relation to **type** Bar if you use object like I suggest.  If there should be no _semantic_ relation this is another case.